# How to convert a raw pdf file string to base64?

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, base64

I am trying to convert a basic raw pdf file string to base64. The base64 is generated correctly but when i decode it to an actual pdf file, the file can't be generated.

I have tried several other methods, tried the Charset.UTF_8 as well but nothing seems to be working.

I cannot use the actual pdf file asI get the string from another service call so it will always be a raw pdf file string

```
        public String get() throws CustomException, IOException {

            String testPDf = "%PDF-1.4\n" +
                "%âãÏÓ\n" +
                "1 0 obj\n" +
                "<< /Type /Catalog\n" +
                "   /Pages 2 0 R\n" +
                ">>\n" +
                "endobj\n" +
                "2 0 obj\n" +
                "<< /Type /Pages\n" +
                "   /Kids [3 0 R]\n" +
                "   /Count 1\n" +
                ">>\n" +
                "endobj\n" +
                "3 0 obj\n" +
                "<< /Type /Page\n" +
                "   /Parent 2 0 R\n" +
                "   /Resources << /Font << /F1 << /Type /Font\n" +
                "                                /Subtype /Type1\n" +
                "                                /BaseFont /Helvetica\n" +
                "                             >> >>\n" +
                "   /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]\n" +
                "   /Contents 4 0 R\n" +
                ">>\n" +
                "endobj\n" +
                "4 0 obj\n" +
                "<< /Length 55 >>\n" +
                "stream\n" +
                "BT\n" +
                "/F1 18 Tf\n" +
                "100 100 Td\n" +
                "(Hello, World!) Tj\n" +
                "ET\n" +
                "endstream\n" +
                "endobj\n" +
                "xref\n" +
                "0 5\n" +
                "0000000000 65535 f\n" +
                "0000000018 00000 n\n" +
                "0000000077 00000 n\n" +
                "0000000175 00000 n\n" +
                "0000000451 00000 n\n" +
                "trailer\n" +
                "<< /Size 5\n" +
                "   /Root 1 0 R\n" +
                ">>\n" +
                "startxref\n" +
                "561\n" +
                "%%EOF";

        testPDf = testPDf.replaceAll("\n", "");

        testPDf = toBase64(testPDf);

        return testPDf;
    }

    public static String toBase64(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
        return encoded;
    }
```

I am using an online converter to test the generatedbase64.

Comment: `testPDf = testPDf.replaceAll("\n", "");` are you sure you should be doing this? As far as I know newlines in a pdf file are significant.

Comment: "the file can't be generated." that is not an error description. What is the issue? Be more specific. Reviewing the following links might help you to improve the question: [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [The Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) may be able to help with any other questions using correctly this site.

Comment: You are not encoding the original "file" as you erased the newlines. At least it is not the exact original "file".

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have tried it both with that line and without it does not change anything.

Comment: @aled When you put the base64 into an online converter, it does not generate a correct pdf file

Comment: File is corrupt. What exactly do you mean by a *raw pdf file string*?

Comment: Right, I see, yes

Comment: @KJ I am open to any suggstion you might have to converting the raw pdf file string to  base64 string

Comment: @KJ that raw pdf string example was generated by openAi so it might be a badly generated one. What about a more generic solution to any raw pdf string

Answer (score 0):

Your coding is almost there but there are a few small errors that will lead to instant failure.
The result if code runs correctly should produce text low on the page as seen here.
[image]

However you need to make some adjustments primarily based on EOL's.

When a PDF is read it starts at the end so those xref values are critical but that is down to the way the file is constructed using either \r \n or \n\r so the expected first position value after the start pointer  will vary. I use windows thus my values are inclusive of \n\r. so possibilities may be ...0015 or ...0016 (nix) or ...0016 or ...0017 (win).

```
xref
0 5
0000000000 65535 f
0000000017 00000 n
0000000074 00000 n
0000000143 00000 n
0000000434 00000 n
trailer
<< /Size 5
   /Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
539
%%EOF
```

Now for other problems is those `...f` and `...n` in windows will automatically be a 2 byte ending but for Linux or Mac they need an extra space before the return e.g. `...f \n` and ALL returns need preserving in many cases.

All that withstanding. You will still get a blank page for 2 more reasons one is the Resources code stack is not correctly closed by matching brackets. There should be 3 pairs.

```
   /Resources << /Font << /F1 << /Type /Font
                                /Subtype /Type1
                                /BaseFont /Helvetica
                             >> >> >>
```

the second problem for placing the text is the order of coding should be `position TD /font tf (text) Tj` like this reordering.

```
4 0 obj
<< /Length 49 >>
stream
BT
100 100 TD
/F1 18 Tf
(Hello, World!) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj
```

If reducing whitespace is the aim there are line endings that MUST be retained. So this is more compacted and works in Acrobat compatible readers. Thus this is what you will need for conversion to base64.
[image]

Linux EOLs (note the space characters before returns in the xref table).

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Kids [3 0 R]/Count 1>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica>>>>>>/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 44 >>
stream
BT 100 100 TD/F1 18 Tf (Hello, World!) Tj ET
endstream
endobj
xref
0 5
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000060 00000 n 
0000000112 00000 n 
0000000265 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 5/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
358
%%EOF
```

Like this (compacted.b64)

```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```

You can see that working here https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file